# Get categories order by their posts in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get top 5 categories by the number of their posts, example:

```
Cat 1 = 10 posts
Cat 2 = 7 posts
Cat 3 = 5 posts
Cat 4 = 3 posts
Cat 5 = 2 posts
```

> I know I can get my categories with their posts by eager load and
>   count the posts number of each category but that doesn't give me `asc`
>   order in categories so i was thinking of join query.

here is what I've made so far and has this issues

1. I cannot put status of posts (just get postes with published status and count them only)
2. I get this error

   `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'publish' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from`categories`inner join`posts`on`posts`.`categories`=`categories`.`id`where`publish`= 1 limit 5)`

## code

```
$categoriesbyposts = Category::where('publish', '=', 1)
  ->join('posts', 'posts.categories', '=', 'categories.id')
  // ->where('posts.publish', '=', 1)
  ->take(5)
  ->get();
```

**PS:** I might need to mention there is no `category_id` column in my posts table i am using 3rd table for that matter named `post_categories` and it gets `post_id` and `category_id`.

Any idea?

## Update

`post model`

```
public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'post_categories', 'post_id', 'category_id');
    }
```

`category model`

```
public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post_categories');
    }
```

## Update 2

I ended up with code below and it returns me 5 posts instead of 5 categories!

```
$categoriesbyposts = DB::table('categories')
            ->where('categories.publish', '=', 1)
            ->join('post_categories', 'post_categories.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_categories.post_id')
            ->groupby('categories.id')
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Can you post migration code for posts table or tell us if category is not null in posts? and what is the column name of category in posts table?

Comment: Have you considered using a `group by` clause

Comment: if you are using 3rd table, either you need to mention the third table in join and also I am thinking why you have not defined relationship between category and post models?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I know I should mention 3rd table as well, honestly i'm blocked at the moment :) PS: i will update the question.

Comment: @kellymandem I'm open for all kind of solutions, feel free to add your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know what the results are

```
$results = DB::select('
    SELECT c.category_name, c.slug, COUNT(pc.post_id) AS `post_count`
    FROM categories AS c JOIN post_categories AS pc
    ON c.id = pc.category_id
    JOIN posts AS p
    ON posts.id = post_categories.post_id
    WHERE c.publish = 1 AND p.publish = 1
    GROUP BY category_name
    ORDER BY post_count DESC
    LIMIT 5
');
```

Another alternative would be

```
$results = Category::selectRaw('categories.category_name, categories.slug,  COUNT(post_categories.post_id) AS `post_count`')
            ->join('post_categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'post_categories.category_id')
            ->join('posts', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_categories.post_id')
            ->whereRaw('categories.publish = 1 AND posts.publish = 1')
            ->groupBy('category_name')
            ->orderBy('post_count', 'DESC')
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Care to explain what this does?

Comment: The `join` to the `posts` table seems unnecessary to me. Unless you want to filter on this table, remove it.

Comment: @Namoshek i have just edited it and thank you for the heads up on that one

Comment: @Ibu the query gets all the category_names and counts the number of posts associated with each category where `publish` in the `categories` table is truthy and then orders them in descending order, where the category_name with the most posts comes first and then gets the top five

Comment: thanks but seems more like database query rather than php, would you mind convert it to something that i can use?

Comment: @mafortis before i update my answer, i would like to know, is the query working on your side and just to point out i believe the answer i have given is something you can use because i pulled it right out of the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries)

Comment: bro i cannot tell if it's working or not as long as i can't use it at all. i can give you answer once i can use it.

Comment: sorry for late respond, your edited answer works however I think there is something less, **1** `->whereRaw('categories.publish')` you didn't provide where raw category publish is 1 **2** we don't have same condition about posts we want to count only published posts **3** the output of this code is `categories title` and `post_count` I need their `slug` column as well. How to fix this issues?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182641/discussion-between-kellymandem-and-mafortis).

Comment: I had to add `->selectRaw('categories.slug')` before `->limit(5)` in order to add category slugs in results please edit your answer for others that might some day end up here. THANKS.

Comment: @mafortis i have edited, and am glad you figured it out. All the best to you

Answer (score 0):

please add table name in  where condition which table apply this condition

select * from categories inner join posts on posts.categories=categories.id where categories.publish= 1 limit 5)

Comment: there is names of my tables in my code `categories`, `post_categories`, `posts`